# How to use delegates in correct way / Understanding delegates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delegates, event-handling

use -  C# (.Net Framework 4.5, Visual Studio 2012)

I try to understand such theme like Delegate, and currently I have few points, that must be clarified for me.
I found a lot of different information in internet that describe how to use it, but it's a little bit complicated to understanding for me this theme.

As I understand I must to do few thing for using delegate:

- Create some entity for work with it (that require creating some delegate)
- Declare a delegate type
- Create some method where I call to delegate
- In main class call delegate with required method that use entity (from first point)

all described I show below

[image: Understanding delagates]

**The question** - am I correctly understand all or maybe I'm wrong - please clarify it.

Also another **question** regarding DELEGATE - where is better to put code with DELEGATE - in Console C# application I can create it in any place of used Namespace - as I can show below.

[image: placing of dalagete]

But maybe there is some recommendation/requirements for placing delegate not only for Console application but also for WinForms, WPF etc.

This theme is new for me and I spend a day for understanding it, but still a little bit (or a more) confused with this, finally create this post for better and clear understanding. think it's very powerfull stuff.

**EDIT**

```
namespace SimpleCSharpApp
{
   delegate void myDelagate ();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any experiences with other programming languages? We may be able to explain delegates using terms from the language you know already.

Comment: Unfortunately no, i start to intresting in C# a little bit more that 2 month ago

Comment: All a `delegate` really is, is a pointer to a method and simply defines the signature of a method.  That is the most boiled-down explanation I can think of.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173173(v=vs.90).aspx) is a good read on when to use a `delegate` over say (in this case), an `interface`.

Comment: but i try to understand the method of usage - how can i use it in correct way - about pointer to a function - as I understand i can call to any function automaticaly when some events come

Comment: The first link I sent in my initial reply has a good description of when to use a delegate.  Read that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ho-ho.. you've got something messed up. I didn't quite grasp what problem you are trying to state until I saw the screenshot from VS with red underline under "delegate" declaration.

First, forget about the `public void delegate zczcxxzc` line for a moment. It is somewhat special. First, let's see some standard kinds *) of delegates.

The two most basic ones are:

- `System.Action`
- `System.Func`

Both are generic and looking at their signature for the first time, they may seem overly complex. But, they are really very simple.

For starters, let's limit to bare, parameterless, `System.Action`.

```
private static void myFunction1() { Console.WriteLine("Hello!"); }
private static void myFunction2() { Console.WriteLine("Bye!"); }
private static void myFunction0() { return; }

... // in some function, i.e. Main()
Action myDelegate = null;

myDelegate = new Action( myFunction1 );
myDelegate(); // writes "Hello!"

myDelegate = new Action( myFunction2 );
myDelegate(); // writes "Bye!"

myDelegate = new Action( myFunction3 );
myDelegate(); // does "nothing"
```

Just like "int" holds a number, "string" - text, a "delegate" holds information about "something callable", or, to use some terminology, "something invokable".

First, I **create a delegate** of type "Action" that remembers "myFunction1". Then I invoke/call that delegate - it results in the remembered function being called.

Then, I **create a delegate** of type "Action" that remembers "myFunction2". Then I invoke/call that delegate - it results in the remembered function being called.

Finally, I **create a delegate** of type "Action" that remembers "myFunction3". Then I invoke/call that delegate - it results in the remembered function being called, and nothing happens - but only because the target function did nothing.

Please note that I deliberately say "created a delegate". Each time a `new Action` is executed, a new delegate is created. A "delegate" is just an object, like String "foo" or float[] {1.2, 4.5}.

Also, note that the full syntax for creating delegates used here is `new Action(...)`. Just like creating any object - new + typename + construction parameters. Yet another sign that a "delegate" is just an object.

Another thing to note is that I did not write `new Action( myFunction1() )`. I did not want to CALL the method and get its result and give that result to the constructor of Action. I wrote `new Action( myFunction1 )`. I gave **the function itself** to the constructor.

But, then, what is an "Action"? System.Action is a class. Like String, or Socket or WebClient. Nothing special here. So, we have a "class" whose objects can remember what-function-should-be-called. Cool.

Therefore some compare delegates to "function pointers". But that's not fully right. Function pointers can remember **what function** to call. Delegates can remember what **method** to call. Remember the difference? In my example above, I deliberately wrote `static` at each `myFunction`. Those can be called object-less/target-less. You just need their name and you can call them from anywhere. To call them, a simple dumb pointer would be enough.

Now, delegates can do more. They can work on **methods**. But methods need to be invoked against an object..

```
class GuineaPig
{
    public static void Squeak() { Console.WriteLine("Ieek!"); }

    public void Well() { Console.WriteLine("actually"); }
    public void IDontKnow() { Console.WriteLine("what they do"); }
}

GuineaPig.Squeak(); // says 'ieek'

Action myDelegate = null;
myDelegate = new Action( GuineaPig.Squeak );
myDelegate(); // writes "ieek"

// GuineaPig.Well(); // cannot do!
// myDelegate = new Action( GuineaPig.Well ); // cannot do!
```

Ok, making a delegate to a static function in other class was easy - just had to say exactly what-function-from-what-class. Again just like calling, but without parenthesis.

But, if you try uncommenting the references to non-static methods, it will not compile. Looking at the `GuineaPig.Well` - that's obvious. It's not static, it needs to be called against OBJECT, not CLASS. For that very same reason, the delegate could not be created. Let's fix that:

```
class GuineaPig
{
    public void Well() { Console.WriteLine("actually"); }
    public void IDontKnow() { Console.WriteLine("what they do"); }
}

GuineaPig myPiggie = new GuineaPig();

myPiggie.Well(); // ok! writes "actually"

Action myDelegate = null;
myDelegate = new Action( myPiggie.Well ); // ok!

myDelegate(); // ok! writes "actually".
```

Note how classname was replaced with objectvariable during the creation of the delegate. The syntax is preserved: just like calling, but without parens. But, what's all the fuss about "methods" vs "functions"..

Delegates can store not only 'what method' to be called, but also **what object** to call them upon.

```
class GuineaPig
{
    public string Name;

    public void Well() { Console.WriteLine("I'm " + Name); }
}

GuineaPig myPiggie1 = new GuineaPig { Name = "Bubba" };
GuineaPig myPiggie2 = new GuineaPig { Name = "Lassie" };

Action myDelegate = null;

myDelegate = new Action( myPiggie1.Well );
myDelegate(); // -> Bubba

myDelegate = new Action( myPiggie2.Well );
myDelegate(); // -> Lassie

myPiggie1 = myPiggie2 = null;

myDelegate(); // -> Lassie
```

Now that is something you cannot do with plain function pointers. (Although with very smart function pointers you could.. but, let's leave that).

Note how the fact that "Well" was to be called on "pig#2" was stored inside the delegate object. The "myPiggie2" variable was irrelevant. I could nullify it. The delegate remembered both target and method.

System.Action is just one of the family. It's the simpliest, no params, no returns.. But there are many of them, they can get parameters (`Action<string, int>`) they can return values (`Func<int>`) or both (`Func<string,int>`). Yet, constantly speaking in terms of `Func<int,float,string,int,int,bool,decimal>` is somewhat ... obscure.

Ok. Let's finally get to the point of all this babbling. Sorry if you knew all of that, but I wanted to be clear.

A "delegate" is all about remembering "target" and "method". In fact, if you ever inspect a delegate in the debugger (or check what Intellisense says after the "dot"), you will see two properties, Target and Method. They are just what their names stand for.

Let's imagine you want to create your own type of a delegate. A type that would not be called `Func<int,int,int,bool,bool,Zonk,string>`, but rather, "MyStudentFilteringDelegate".

Now, whole point is, that in C# **you cannot take `&`(address) of a function** easily, and also **you cannot overload the operator()**. This results in **you being unable** to write your own delegate-like classes.

You cannot just write:

```
class MyStudentFilteringDelegate
{
     public object Target;
     public somethingstrange*  MethodPointer;

     // other code
}
```

because, even if you actually managed to follow that idea, somewhere at the end you would find that:

```
MyDelegate dd = new MyDelegate ( ... );
dd(); // is just impossible!!!
```

At least, in current C# version 4.5 or 5.

You just cannot overload the "call"/"invoke" operator, hence you would not be able to fully implement your own, custom-named, delegate type. You'd be stuck at Actions and Funcs for ever.

Now recall that red underline under the `public void delegate xxx` I asked you to temporarily forget.

```
public bool delegate MyStudentFilteringDelegate( Student stud );
```

This line **does not create any delegate**. This line defines a **type of a delegate**. It is perfectly the same as `Func<Student,bool>`, with custom name. *)

In fact, the compiler converts the line to:

```
public class MyStudentFilteringDelegate : some_framework_Delegate_class
{
    // object Target {get;} - inherited from base class
    // MethodInfo Method {get;} - inherited from base class, too
}
```

so that it is a **class**, and so that you can now create a **delegate** object:

```
var dd = new MyStudentFilteringDelegate ( ... ); // like normal class!
dd(); // ok!;
```

As the class is special, compiler-generated, it can break rules. It's 'call'/'invoke' operator is overloaded, so you can "call" the delegate as it were a method.

Please note that despite the strange notation:

```
public bool delegate MyStudentFilteringDelegate( Student stud );
```

the `MyStudentFilteringDelegate` is a **class**, just like Action or Func or String or WebClient are. The `delegate` keyword is just a marker for the compiler to know what transformation it should apply to that line to generate a proper "delegate type" (class).

Now, to actually answer your other question:

It is **really** irrelevant where you put the *delegate type declaration*. You may write `public void delegate XYZ(...)` anywhere you like. Just as you may place a *class declaration* just about anywhere.

You may place class declarations at default(no-namespace) scope, at some namespace, or inside a class. So, as the delegate-type is just a class, you may also delcare new delegate types at default(no-namespace) scope, at some namespace, or inside a class:

```
public class Xc {}
public void delegate Xd();

namespace WTF {
    public class Xc {}
    public void delegate Xd();

    class Whatever {
        public class Xc {}
        public void delegate Xd();
    }
}
```

Note that I completely deliberately named them identically. That's no error. First are named `::global.Xc` and `::global.Xd`, the second pair is named `WTF.Xc` and `WTF.Xd` and the final pair is named `WTF.Whatever.Xc` and `WTF.Whatever.Xd`. Just like normal clases.

To decide where to place those declarations, use the same rules as you use for classes. Ie. if you place text-processing classes in namespace `MyApp.Text.Parsing`, then all the delegatetypes related to that text-processing should sit in that namespace too. But, even so, that's purely cosmetical and organizational. Place/define them at whatever scope it makes sense for you.

EDIT:
*) actually, historically, it was all other way around. The `delegate` keyword and compiler trick is **older** than the Action and Func classes. At .Net 2.0, the Action/Func did not exist. The only way to create/use a delegate was to define your own new delegate type (or find/guess some suitable one somewhere deep in the system's namespaces). Keep in mind that every new delegate-type is a new class. Not convertible to any other class, not even similarly-looking. It was so frustratingly tiresome and hard to mantain, that at .Net 3.5 they finally included "general purpose generic delegate types" in the framework. From that point of time, Action/Func are increasingly often used, because even if they are harder to read, they are .. universal. `System.Func<Student,bool>` can be passed "anywhere", and you don't have a problem that 'bool delegate StudentFilter()`from one library does not match`bool delegate StudentSelector()` from anoother one.

Comment: Thats a lot of typing.

Comment: I train a lot :P Actually, about 35 minutes.

Comment: thanks for such explanation. Now situation more-less clear for me (at least some moments). but if Delagate just remember tha method that i need to call, what is the difference if i call to the method without delegate and if i create delegate that can call same method and that call this delegate? Or i miss some additional area for usage delagate? As gisek wrote it can be used together with lamba expressions, means it's only the common area where it can be used?

Comment: @Kirill: No, with lambdas it's exactly the other way around. But, answering in order: (1) the difference is extra possibility of abtraction. Imagine you have a Timer/Counter class that has a method that "Increases it by 5 units". It may be useful for some cases, but actually, it's hardly usable in the general terms. So, a "natural step forward" is to add a parameter to it called `int count` and make this method add that `count` instead of just always 5. This makes this method **a little harder to use** but increases usability. Harder? Of course. Now you must know if 5/50/500 is much or little.

Comment: Now, imagine you write/design a class that reads some directory on your disk and looks for the biggest file. Quite easy to write. Quite usable, too, especially when you want to cleanup some old logs etc. But, later you might want to also find all zero-sized files, because some poorly-written application spams your disk with those too. Would you write a second class/method that now also reads directory and looks for zero-sized files? What if later you want to find the oldest file, or most recently modified one?>

Comment: Clearly, you could make the directory-searching class more general and more capable, but still somewhoe the **caller must specify what he wants**. But, covering all the ideas of *what file could be wanted* and passing them by parameter is insane. "Traditionally" you would now define interface like `IFileScore` with method `double CheckScore(File f);` which would return "how good the file is", and the directory-scanner require to provide it. Or, better, `IFileComparer` to compare two files - which one is better. Now whoever wants to scan-a-dir, can provide his own file-scoring..

Comment: So - it works. But now just to say "I want the oldest File" you must: declare a class that implements IFileComparison that implements Compare(File,File) that does `return f1.Date < f2.Date`. It's all because the comparison is **code** and you cannot pass **code as parameters** (remember it for later). If you could, you'd just pass the correct `<` operator that works on `DateTime`. But, hey, with delegates you can remember and pass methods? So, let the directory-scanner take a `bool (File, File)` delegate that compares two files! No more Interface, no more three-liner Class.

Comment: I mean, no more dozens of tiny interfaces and no more hundreds of tiny classes in an average project. Now you just define `bool dateComparison(File f, File f2) {return f.Date < f2.Date; }` and pass it as a delegate to the directory-scanner. With correct delegate declarations, it could be as simple as `new Scanner{ How = dateComparison }.Scan("c:\temp")`. Less code to write, less code to read and mantain, less places for bugs. This way we've just made the directory-scanner more abstract, more general-purpose. But, in turn, it's a bit harder to use: it takes not an `enum How` but a method.

Comment: Here also you can see another thing: the directory-scanner now **delegates** part of its job to the "unknown thing" that was passed to him as parameter. It no longer nows how to compare files on its own. This is how "delegate(s)" got their name, and this is their most basic usage: they are tiny interfaces that allow you to abstract away from some operation. This has been instantly incorporated in the idea of `events`. Imagine all the fuss if you had to implement a "IMouseClick" interface anytime you just want something to happen on-click.

Comment: In C#, 'events' are driven by delegates: at minimum, you want pass a "method", a "handler", that will get fired when event occurs. So, you pass a "MouseClick" delegate that remembers your "button3_Click" method. The `event` really just stores a set/list of all delegates that were `+=`'ed to it. There's almost nothing more there.

Comment: (2) Now, Lambdas and Delegates. As you probably heard, lambdas are "anonymous functions". Focus on the exact naming: **anonymous** - so - **unnamed**. How do you use a method that does not have a name?! You cannot refer to it like `myObject.myMethod3123("hey!")` because.. anonymous means **no-name** *). There's just no way to do that. This is where delegates kick in again. Whenever you use a lambda-expression, it returns you a delegate that remembers that anonymous function. This is your only tiny way to access that anonmethod.*) With that delegate, you cal call that method, or pass it around.

Comment: What for? Well, to further reduce the code! Remember the directory-scanner? The most minimal usage/implementation we could do was: `bool dateComparison(File f, File f2) {return f.Date < f2.Date; } ... (later) new Scanner{ How = dateComparison }.Scan("c:\temp");`. Sure, writing little functions is far less nuisance than classes, but we can reduce it further: if that `dateComparison` is **really used only here**, we don't need to even NAME it: `new Scanner{ How = delegate(File f, File f2){return f.Date < f2.Date; } }.Scan("c:\temp");`, just saved ourselves from writing a function.

Comment: But, the syntax is ugly. And hardly readable. That's an old example. With recent C# compiler, we can write the same with a **lambda expression**: instead of that `delegate(..){..}` you can just write: `new Scanner{ How = (f1, f2) => f.Date < f2.Date }.Scan("c:\temp");`. The compiler is smart enough to guess that F1 F2 are Files and that all of this is an anonymous function. In simple cases, you don't even have to write `return`. You might wonder what's all the fuss about reducing the text..

Comment: Look at this example: `students.FindAllThat(stud => stud.Year==2013).OrderThemBy(stud => stud.Group).TakeFirstThat(stud => stud.FirstName.BeginsWith("Fred"))`. It scans a list of `students`, gets only those from 2013 year, orders them by the Group (IT, Biology, etc), and blah.. Imagine how many "IStudentGroupComparers" or "IStudentYearFinder" you would need to implement if there were no lambdas/anonfunctions/delegates here. Each of those `stud => stud.Group` selectors is a tricky small delegate! **)

Comment: But, as with everything, it's very easy to overdo. This syntax is not that readable (at least for beginners) and it has some 'gotchas'. And, it's really usable to replace an interface-with-one-method. If you are trying to abstract-away from something and that ends up with an interface with more than one method (i.e. IList: Add, Remove, etc), then you have no way of collapsing it to a delegate/lambda. They are just holders for one method. Can't do more.

Comment: Clarifications: *) anonymous methods actually have names. Compiler generates them automatically. They are ugly like `afas123<>4` and since they use `<>` characters, you **cannot** use that names in the code. But, you can inspect your classes with Reflection and you will find them! `typeof(MyClassWithLambdas).GetMethods()` and check what you got. Reflection gave you a number of `MethodInfo`s that describe all methods, including lambdas with funny names. Btw. do you remember the `object Target, MethodInfo Method` from a delegte? yep, that's the same MethodInfo.

Comment: **) This example highly resembles LINQ. LINQ gets 'delegate' and 'method passing' concept even further. Instead of taking `Action<..>` or `Func<..>` delegate, you can take `Expression<Action<..>>` or `Expression<Func<..>>` as a parameter. The caller will then be able to ONLY anonymous lambdas, they will not be able to pass normal delegates or normal methods to it. But, in turn, the compiler will ... not generate method at all. It will generate "description" of what that method does, like: "take Param1, take Param2, compare them with Operator<" and pass this thing to the method as `Expression`

Comment: This in turn allows your method to take that expression, analyze it, and literally **know** what the user wants, not just "call it". With some tricks, you can also change the contents of the expression (like automatically adding "if != null" everywhere) and many other thing. But, heh, as with any higher-order things, that gets yet more complicated and I think I got quite far off the topic already. But, to say it simply, it's yet another step in 'evolution of code': concretecode->`abstract`->`interface`->anonymous->lambdas->expressions. But, it's all just tools. None is best for everything!

Comment: thanks for such explanation, i got a little bit better explanation for my in this questions

Answer (score 1):

Delegates in c# are a little bit like a replacement for function pointers in C++. There are plenty of usages for them. You can use them to:

1. Crate an inline implementation for an event.
2. Pass a callback to a function.
3. Create a array of "functions" you can call in a loop.

From my experience the first usage is the most common.

```
Button.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)  => {/*you do something here*/};
```

Which can be simplified by a lamba expression:

```
Button.Click += (sender, args) => {/*you do something here*/};
```

You provide some behavior to a button click not having to create a separate method for it.

Regarding to the second part of your question, I usually put delegates declarations in separate files.

Comment: So you just create some file with nemespace for delagate? like `namespace SimpleCSharpApp
{
   delegate void myDelagate ();
}`

Comment: @Kirill Exactly, but this is what I do, actually it's the metter of your individual preferences. I like to keep things separate to avoid mess in my files.

Comment: And regarding first question - am i correct in undertsnding of a delegates usage? and if yes it's possible to create some abject and than call delegate and each time when i do something with created object delegate do all requested work?

Comment: @Kirill Yes, this is what you call a 'callback' or maybe better an 'event handler' :) But you will usually want co combine it with an event (you can create your own events). Also you should read about Actions which are a nice wrapper around delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate declarations can be placed in any source file with public and internal accessibility. I personally place them at the top of a class source for which it is most applicable.

For instance if I have a specialized event delegate that takes CustomEventArgs as a parameter, I will put the delegate declaration at the top of that file:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
   public delegate void SpecialEventDelegate(object sender, CustomEventArgs e);

   public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs {
      // implementation details
   }
}
```

Another option is to put delegates together in a single source file ... I haven't seen this done and would be subject to coding guidelines.

A delegate generally has two qualifications:

- A declaration of a method or class member
- A reference to a method or class member

The first qualification is the declaration of a delegate:

```
   public delegate void SpecialEventDelegate(object sender, CustomEventArgs e);
```

... or using [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
   Action<object, CustomEventArgs> // similar declaration to the SpecialEventDelegate above
```

Since an event handler (declared delegate) generally does not have a return type (`void`), a `Func<TResult>` would not be used. A Func delegate requires a return type:

```
   Func<bool> // a delegate that return true/false
```

See the linked MSDN articles for more on `Func<TResult>` and `Action`. I only included references to these for completeness and insight on newer declaration methods. `Func<TResult>` and `Action` are specialized wrappers for the `delegate`.

The second qualification for a delegate is a reference to a method or class member. I may have a private method that acts as a handler for specific needs. Say a FileIO object needs a specific file handler for different types of files - that is, .XML, .TXT, .CSV:

```
namespace MyNamespace {

   public delegate Stream OpenFile(FileInfo FileSpec);

}
```

Now any object can implement it's own `OpenFile` definition based on the file type but must return a `Stream` object.

```
class XMLHandler : IFileHandler {

   private OpenFile xmlFileReader;

   // implementation of interface
   public OpenFile FileHandler {
      get { return xmlFileReader; }
   }

   public XMLHandler(){
      xmlFileReader = MyXmlFileReader;  // references the private method in this class
   }

   private Stream MyXmlFileReader(FileInfo XmlFileSpec) {
      // implementation specific to this class
   }

}

interface IFileHandler {

   OpenFile FileHandler { get; }

}
```

By using both a delegate declaration and an interface, we can pass the `XMLHandler` object as an `IFileHandler` and only expose the delegate via the `FileHandler` property without exposing the entire object. Note that the method referenced by the delegate is private. This is a special benefit of the delegate (and Func, Action).