# Delegate how it works

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, delegates

use C#, .Net Framework 4.5, visual Studio 2012

After some [**theory**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19963454/2012219) try to create some delegate in C#.

Currently create next code

```
namespace SimpleCSharpApp
{
public delegate void MyDelegate();
class Program
{   
    private static string name;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //my simple delegate
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
        name = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        MyDelegate myD;
        myD = new MyDelegate(TestMethod);

        //Generic delegate
        Func<Int32, Int32, Int32> myDel = new Func<Int32, Int32, Int32>(Add);
        Int32 sum = myDel(12, 33);
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        Console.ReadLine();

        //call static method from another class
        myD = new MyDelegate(NewOne.Hello);
    }
    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name);
    }
    public static Int32 Add(Int32 a, Int32 b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    }
}
```

And anther class

```
namespace SimpleCSharpApp
{
 sealed class NewOne
{
    static public void Hello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm method from another class");
    }
}
}
```

As result got next

[image: My result]

So the **question** - why delegate`MyDelegate` not work and generic variant - work? Where i'm wrong.

And another **question** - i can call displayed sample method something like this

```
        //calling method
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
        name = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
        TestMethod();
        //from another class
        NewOne.Hello();
```

whats advantages i got when use delegates? Or it's just a variant how can i use delegate and "full power" i can see when can try it with lamba-extensions and events? (just coming to this chapter - not read yet - whant to understand delegate better).

Comment: You're not calling `myD` anywhere. Try this: `myD();`

Comment: advantages of delegate is that you can pass it any valid function. this mean you can extend and change the behaviour of a class or a method very easily. disadvantage are that are harder to debug and (from my point of view) if used recklessly makes the code unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your first question, your delegate didn't work because you never invoked it. You just created an instance of it here:

```
MyDelegate myD;
myD = new MyDelegate(TestMethod);
```

But nowhere in your program do you actually invoke `myD`. Try calling it like this:

```
MyDelegate myD;
myD = new MyDelegate(TestMethod);
myD();
```

To answer your second question, the primary advantage of using delegates is that you can refer to a method without invoking it immediately. For example, suppose you want to pass a method to another function for some additional processing:

```
private void Repeat(MyDelegate method, int times)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        method();
}

Repeat(NewOne.Hello, 5);
```

You're allowing the `Repeat` method to take control over how and when `NewOne.Hello` gets invoked, without requiring `Repeat` to know which method needs to be invoked at compile time. This idea is at the core of some programming techniques (see [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)). One big one you may be familiar with already is [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx), which uses delegates for manipulating collections in an efficient and elegant way.

Comment: oh, now it's clear for me - finally! 2 and half night give me some results!!! thanks for explanation!!!

Comment: also found that i can call it like `Repeat(myD, 5);`

Comment: @Kirill Correct, you can use a delegate variable directly or reference the method itself which implicitly converts the method to a delegate variable to pass to `Repeat`.

Comment: @Kirill You can also use [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx), e.g. `Repeat(() => Console.WriteLine("Lambda"), 5)`

Comment: need a liitle bit more time to read and try lambda function - but as i see now - it provide much compact code, and i think (i don't see now due to lack of knoweladge) provide additional capabilities for codding, but still neet a lot of reading and practice...

Comment: this `=>` as i see - `repeat()` must use (this symbol `=>` ) as parameter1 `Console.WriteLine("Lambda")` and as parameter2 `5`...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're never invoking the `myD` delegate. This is easier to miss with `MyDelegate` because you're not passing anything into it or taking any return value.

```
MyDelegate myD;
myD = new MyDelegate(TestMethod);
myD(); // executes TestMethod
```

For your second question, the short version is that delegates are primarily useful in event handlers and in LINQ (and similar methods).

Comment: thanks, as wrote @p.s.w.g - you are right too...and maybe any comments regarding second question?

Comment: @Kirill I've just added a second paragraph about the second question.

Comment: not yet read about event and LINQ, ok if it's became clear for me later  when i read about it - ok, so think that such type of usage - just simple usage for delegates